# Updating an entity in Entity Framework which contains lists of other entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to update objects in Entity Framework and I'd like to know what the best way of updating Entities that contain a List of other Entities.

Consider the following example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace EntityFrameworkUpdateSketch
{
public class A
{
    [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int Akey {get;set;}

    public string Aname { get; set; }

    public virtual List<B> Blist {get;set;}

    public A()
    {
        Blist = new List<B>();
    }
}

public class B
{
    public virtual A owner { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("owner")]
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public int Akey { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int Order { get; set; }


    public string Bname { get; set; }
}

public class Database: DbContext
{
    public DbSet<A> As { get; set; }
    public DbSet<B> Bs { get; set; }
}

public class Program
{        
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Make a new object

        using (Database db = new Database())
        {
            A intodb = new A();

            intodb.Akey = 1;                

            intodb.Aname = "Name of A object";

            intodb.Blist.Add(new B() { Bname = "Name of B object one",Order=1 });

            intodb.Blist.Add(new B() { Bname = "Name of B object two",Order=2 });

            db.As.Add(intodb);

            db.SaveChanges();
        }

        // Update the object in database

        using (Database db = new Database())
        {                       
            // Imagine I got "update" from somewhere else

            A update = new A();

            update.Akey = 1;

            update.Aname = "New Name of A object";

            update.Blist.Add(new B() { Bname = "New Name of B object one" ,Akey=1, Order=1});

            update.Blist.Add(new B() { Bname = "New Name of B object two", Akey = 1, Order = 2 });

            update.Blist.Add(new B() { Bname = "A whole new object 3", Akey = 1, Order = 3 });


            db.Entry<A>(update).State = EntityState.Modified;                

            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
}
```

I have an object "A" that contains a List as a property.

In the first half of my demonstration program I create a new object of type A and then store it in the database.

In the second half, I make a new object called A and I want to update the object in the database with new values- I want to change the B names and I want to add a new B object to the list.

This works for changing A , but the subcategories B don't work- they don't have new names.

The reason I'm trying to do this is because I'm trying to write a PUT method for a MVC WebAPI controller that stores its data in Entity Framework. I'm getting a new object passed in to my PUT action and I want to replace an existing object in the database.

I can't delete A and re add it (although this does work) because this breaks foreign keys- I have cascading deletes in my "real" solution that removes references elsewhere if I delete my A object.

You don't need to know anything about WebAPI or PUT to answer this question.

Comment: What error message are you getting and what version of Entity Framework are you using?

Comment: In the second part you only attach `A` to the context.  EF never knows about the new `B`s. `db.Entry<>().State` only affects scalar properties, no navigation properties.

Comment: @Nick I'm using EF 6.1. There aren't any error messages, just the database isn't being updated as I'd like

Comment: @GertArnold What should I do? I can attach all of my new B, but what I really want to do is automatically destroy all existing B that aren't in the new object. Should I run a separate query, and if so what should it look like?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a program that works, but could do with improving. All this program does now is delete all B objects in the database that belong to A, then re-add. This works but it seems bad. Any improvements?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace EntityFrameworkUpdateSketch
{
public class A
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int Akey {get;set;}

    public string Aname { get; set; }

    public virtual List<B> Blist {get;set;}

    public A()
    {
        Blist = new List<B>();
    }
}

public class B
{
    public virtual A owner { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("owner")]
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public int Akey { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int Order { get; set; }


    public string Bname { get; set; }
}

public class Database: DbContext
{
    public DbSet<A> As { get; set; }
    public DbSet<B> Bs { get; set; }
}

public class Program
{        
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Make a new object            
        using (Database db = new Database())
        {
            A intodb = new A();

            intodb.Akey = 1;                

            intodb.Aname = "Name of A object";

            intodb.Blist.Add(new B() { Bname = "Name of B object one",Order=1 });

            intodb.Blist.Add(new B() { Bname = "Name of B object two",Order=2 });

            db.As.Add(intodb);

            db.SaveChanges();
        }

        // Update the object in database

        using (Database db = new Database())
        {                       
            // Imagine I got "update" from somewhere else

            A update = new A();

            update.Akey = 1;

            update.Aname = "New Name of A object";

            update.Blist.Add(new B() { Bname = "New Name of B object one" ,Akey=1, Order=1});

            update.Blist.Add(new B() { Bname = "New Name of B object two", Akey = 1, Order = 2 });

            update.Blist.Add(new B() { Bname = "A whole new object 3", Akey = 1, Order = 3 });


            db.Entry<A>(update).State = EntityState.Modified;                

            // Clear all existing B objects attached to the updated object

            var query = from c in db.Bs.AsEnumerable() where  c.Akey==update.Akey select c;

            foreach (var z in query)
            {
                db.Bs.Remove(z);
            }

            // Readd B objects

            foreach (var i in update.Blist)
            {
                db.Bs.Add(i);
            }

            db.SaveChanges();                              
        }
    }

}
}
```